# Error with pulling data from Yahoo Finance

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to pull data from Yahoo Finance via Pandas. I have used similar pulls before, but haven't faced any issue before this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
from dateutil import parser
from pandas_datareader import data
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

end_date=dt.datetime.today()

begdate = end_date + relativedelta(years=-10)

data1 = data.get_data_yahoo('^DJI',begdate,end_date,interval='m')
```

This is the error I am getting

```
RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv
```

I am using Python 3.5

Comment: the site is down thus the problem

Comment: Exprator is right. Wait till they fix the issue

Comment: Yahoo have changed there API endpoint. This issue is currently [discussed](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/315) on the pandas-datareader repo.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT:
This issue has been fixed as of [v0.5.0](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/releases) of pandas-reader. The fix below no longer applies.

---

As pointed out by others, the API endpoint has changed and a patch has been [made](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/315) but hasn't been merged to the `master` branch of `pandas-datareader` yet (as of 2017-05-21 6:19 UTC). The fix is at this [branch](https://github.com/rgkimball/pandas-datareader/commits/fix-yahoo) by [Rob Kimball](https://github.com/rgkimball) ([Issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/315) | [PR](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/pull/331)). For a temporary fix (until the patch is merged into `master`), try:

```
$ pip install git+https://github.com/rgkimball/pandas-datareader@fix-yahoo --upgrade
```

Or, in case you want to tweak the source code:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/rgkimball/pandas-datareader
$ cd pandas-datareader
$ git checkout fix-yahoo
$ pip install -e .
```

On Python:

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
print(pdr.__version__)  # Make sure it is '0.4.1'.
pdr.get_data_yahoo('^DJI')
```

Comment: the first line of your code solved the problem, thanks ;)