# while fetching data from pandas.DataReader.,its returning remote data error

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

Code:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime

start =datetime.datetime(2010,1,1)
end   =datetime.datetime(2013,1,1)

prices = web.DataReader(['CSV','BP','XOM'],'yahoo',start ,end)['Adj Close']

prices.head()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error with pulling data from Yahoo Finance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44087113/error-with-pulling-data-from-yahoo-finance)

Comment: so what's the alternative

Comment: For a question to be answerable, it's helpful to give details about error messages and sequences of operations, not just the code. Please consider making an [edit] to your question.